# Invalid use of non-static member where member is const and list-initialised?

Tags: c++, c++11

I have this header:

```
class A{
    const int x;
    typedef std::array<MyClass, x> ARRAY;   // Cannot use x here?

};
```

and in the implementation file:

```
A::A() : x(10) {}
```

but I get compiler errors for the typedef line saying:

> invalid use of non-static data member A::x

I thought `x` only had to be const for use in the array sizing? I really wish to avoid static.

Comment: *"I thought x only had to be const for use in the array sizing?"*. Your thought is wrong: `const` is not enough, it has to be *const **expression*** which means its *value* has to be known to the compiler. In your case, `x` is **not** a const *expression*; it is only a read-only expression (which means, its value is not known to the compiler, but if you attempts to change its value, the compiler will bite you).

Comment: @Nawaz [No answers in comments please](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/320364/2069064)

Comment: This is the second question of yours where you profess that you really wish to avoid static. I'd really rather see you ask about that particular problem of yours. Since you'd actually be able to write better code once that is resolved.

Answer (score 3):

In order to use `x` as a non-type template parameter, it has to be a *core constant expression* - basically it has to be evaluatable at compile-time. A simple `const` is not sufficient criteria, `const` just means it is not modifiable  in the future - it does not mean that it is a known quantity at compile-time.

There is one edge case here which may be causing some confusion in that a `const` integral is a core constant expression in cases like this:

```
const int x = 10;
std::array<int, x> arr; // ok
```

There's no reason to want to avoid `static`. You will want to do something like this:

```
struct A {
    static constexpr int x = 10;
    typedef std::array<MyClass, x> ARRAY;
};
```